# Why does the fullstack-angular generator use Lo-Dash's merge instead of document.set?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongoose, yeoman, lodash

This is the default code for updating:

```
exports.update = function(req, res) {
  if(req.body._id) { delete req.body._id; }
  Thing.findById(req.params.id, function (err, thing) {
    if (err) { return handleError(res, err); }
    if(!thing) { return res.send(404); }
    var updated = _.merge(thing, req.body);
    updated.save(function (err) {
      if (err) { return handleError(res, err); }
      return res.json(200, thing);
    });
  });
};
```

Note the line that says: `var updated = _.merge(thing, req.body);`. This only works for Schema properties that are primitives. Eg. it doesn't work for a schema property that is an array.

The problem is that `thing` is a *mongoose document*, and `req.body` is a *javascript object.*

I have two hypotheses for what the real problem is:

1. [_.merge()](https://lodash.com/docs#merge) requires the first argument to be an object, but it's
   receiving a document.
2. _.merge() only merges when the two objects have equal keys and types. Because one is a document and the other is an object, they're
   different.

Consider this example. `name` is updated properly but `arr` is not. However, *both* are updated properly when I use `thing.set(req.body)` instead of `var updated = _.merge(thing, req.body)`.

**thing.html**

```
<div class="container">
  <form ng-submit="update()">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Name</label>
      <input class="form-control" ng-model="thing.name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Arr</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        ng-repeat="el in thing.arr"
        ng-model="thing.arr[$index]">
    </div>
    <button 
      class="btn btn-default"
      type="submit">
      Update
    </button>
  </form>

  {{thing | json}}
</div>
```

**thing.controller.js (front end)**

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('/api/things')
    .success(function(things) {
      $scope.thing = things[0];
    });
  $scope.update = function() {
    $http.put('/api/things/' + $scope.thing._id, $scope.thing)
      .success(function(newThing) {
        console.log('updated thing: ', newThing);
      })
      .error(function() {
        console.log('unable to update thing');
      });
  };
});
```

**thing.model.js**

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ThingSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  arr: []
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Thing', ThingSchema);
```

**thing.controller.js (backend)**

```
'use strict';

var _ = require('lodash');
var Thing = require('./thing.model');

exports.update = function(req, res) {
  if(req.body._id) { delete req.body._id; }
  Thing.findById(req.params.id, function (err, thing) {
    if (err) { return handleError(res, err); }
    if(!thing) { return res.send(404); }
    var updated = _.merge(thing, req.body);
    updated.save(function (err) {
      if (err) { return handleError(res, err); }
      return res.json(200, thing);
    });
  });
};

function handleError(res, err) {
  return res.send(500, err);
}
```

Two questions:

1. What is the problem with using _.merge()?
2. Why did the creators of the [angular-fullstack generator](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack) choose to use _.merge()? I'm sure they're aware of its behavior, so they must have a reason.

Comment: Yes - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27559061/mongoose-document-set-isnt-working. I had deleted it because I got it working with `set()`, but I just undeleted it for your reference.

Comment: @JohnnyHK Absolutely! You're right, I should have done this in the beginning. I edited the question with the new example.

Comment: You'd need to manually mark the `arr` field as modified in that case as you haven't defined what its elements contain so Mongoose can't tell when it's modified. i.e. `updated.markModified('arr');`

Comment: @JohnnyHK Ok, thanks. Do you think there's an advantage to this over using `set`? Perhaps it's faster because it's only merging the updated things instead of everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling 'markModified' on the _.merge return value (as suggested by a previous answer) didn't resolve this issue for me. The issue Adam Zerner reported is that _merge causes the 'updated' object to contain invalid data for array properties. I am also experiencing this issue using the angular-fullstack generator, for example if I delete elements out of an array this change doesn't get stored in Mongoose/mongo. Calling the set function on the mongoose document (e.g. thing.set(..., as suggested by Zerner) resolves the issue for me.  I also read this discussion thread: https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack/issues/637; it suggests replacing _merge with _extend (see also https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack/issues/310) which also works for me.

Answer (score 1):

you need the user "markModified"
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-markModified

```
var updated = _.merge(store, req.body);
updated.markModified('foo_name');
updated.save(function (err) {
  if (err) {
    return handleError(res, err);
  }
  return res.json(200, store);
});
```

Comment: see user3608315's answer

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded from Lodash 3.10.1 to 4.6.1 (the latest at the time) and _.merge now works as you'd want. I had been having trouble for a while with this, and changing _.merge to _.assign with the latest version of generator-angular-fullstack (3.3.0) wasn't working for me as it did in previous versions. v4.6.1 of Lodash seems to make this work, and though I see a bunch of npm modules with v3.10.1 of Lodash listed as a dependency, I haven't come across anything breaking yet.